# Grails Spring Security caching username

Tags: spring, caching, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

i seem to have a small problem with this line of code:

```
${sec.loggedInUserInfo(field: 'username')}
```

It seems to be caching another user who is logged into the system.The line of code is in all my main html gsp layouts.The weird part is that although its caching,the security side of it still does not take it as the cached name but the actual person logged in which is a good if not great thing. I really need help as to why this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question without a lot more information. What version of Grails are you using? Is this information being cached in the browser or on the server? (e.g. if you clear the cache on the browser does it suddenly show the correct user?) Are you using the cache plugin for Grails? There are a lot of factors at play here...

Comment: Hi Joshua ,i am using grails version 2.3.7. i did not install the cache plugin but only the spring security plugin.I am now leaning towards maybe it being a session issue?  i dont think its caching from the browser as there are numerous users at different pc's using this application. so that eliminates the caching on the browser side.

Comment: @Joshua Moore,Will having this line of code ${sec.loggedInUserInfo(field: 'username')} outside the '<sec:ifLoggedIn>' tag affect why its caching on the server side?

Comment: There is nothing inherent in that code or the lack of that tag that would effect caching. I'm still of the opinion that you have caching turned on at the server level or some type of cache plugin installed that is causing the issue.

Comment: @Joshua Moore,ok thanks for the reply,i also do have this code in my javascript:  $.ajaxSetup({cache: false}); for my ajax methods,do i need to declare something else within my logic which is similar?. Thanks in advance.